# how to create progressbar when file being uploaded by drag and drop

Tags: php, ajax, upload, drag-and-drop, progress

For file uploading i have a progressbar which works great with a form.
This is my form:

```
 <form class="sfmform" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" class="Button Primary" name="upload" value="Upload" />

    </form>
```

and this is the js which generates a progressbar:

```
 /* progression upload status in %*/

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('.sfmform').ajaxForm({
beforeSend: function() {
    status.empty();
    var percentVal = '0%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
},
uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
},
success: function(data) {

    var percentVal = '100%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
    status.html(data);
},
complete: function(data) {

    var percentVal = '0%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
    status.html(data);
},


});
```

Now i also use drag and drop div for uploading files. This is the div for drag and drop:

```
<div class="sfmform" id="drop-area"><h3 class="drop-text">Drag and Drop Files Here</h3></div>
```

How can i call the same progressbar when file is uploaded via drag and drop?